# Use of strings in "switch" statement; Java SE 7

Tags: java, switch-statement, java-7

I wanted to use a String in a switch statement but I read that this feature was available from version java SE 7. I've downloaded it, when I type "java -version" in a console I read:

```
java version "1.7.0_01"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_01-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 21.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

In my Eclipse project, I've modified the "JRE System Library" properties to "JavaSE'1.7".

After all this when I use a string on a switch statement I get an error: `Cannot switch on a value of type string.`

Any clue of what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231907/java-7-switch-statement-with-strings-not-working

Comment: can you pls provide your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Eclipse Indigo 3.7.1 for Java 7 support - this was released at the end of September 2011.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need the latest version of Eclipse (one that supports compiler compliance level of 1.7).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you also go into the project properties in Eclipse and under `Java Compiler` pick the appropriate compiler compliance level?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get latest version of eclipse. eclipse helios would be find for this.

Comment: I was trying it with Eclipse Helios. Finally I have downloaded Eclipse Indigo and it works

Comment: if you go with Eclipse Helios then it should be work. The problem is that you just need to select Java Compiler as 1.7 from Projecs Name -> Properties -> Java Compiler.

Comment: You're right, I've tried it and it works with both Eclipse versions, Helios and Indigo. Thanks!